# What does getValue(constant,number) in jrules signify?

Tags: ilog, jrules

In Jrules, I often encountered the following : `getValue(CONTSANT,5)` . What is the significance of the number after the constant ? I think it means 4 decimal places after the value . Is my assumption correct here ?

Answer (score -1):

The Signature of the method is

```
public String getValue(String key, Locale locale)
```

A Locale object represents a specific geographical, political, or cultural region.

Follow these links:

[irlPropertyManager](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSQP76_8.6.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.ref.res/html/api/html/ilog/rules/util/prefs/IlrPropertyManager.html#getValue(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale))

[Class Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html?is-external=true)

Comment: I already know about the resources mentioned . This is not an answer to my question .